# '<selector>' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular

Before I continue with the question: I have checked the other questions with the same title and I have followed given advices. None of it helped so I decided to open a new question.

I have angular project with one module and multiple components. Dashboard component uses welcome component that is apparently not recognized.

The module has the following code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FrameComponent } from './frame/frame.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert/alert.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FrameComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CardComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    AlertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [CardComponent, WelcomeComponent, AlertComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [FrameComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see, I have imported WelcomeComponent, declared it and exported it.
WelcomeComponent contains the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  message: string;
  welcomeMessage: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Here you can see app-welcome as a selector. It appears to be connected correctly. But when I use it in dashboard.component.html as given from the example

```
<app-welcome [message]="message" [welcomeMessage]="welcomeMessage"></app-welcome>
```

I get the following error:

> Error: src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:18:5 - error NG8001: 'app-welcome' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'app-welcome' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-welcome' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Other errors are related to welcome and welcomeMessage not existing since component is not recognized.

I tried restarting server, running it as --prod. I tried everything that I found. Does anyone know what could this cause?

Comment: put dashboard component in declaration as well.

Comment: It seems to give me other errors now, so I'll consider it as a success. But why in the name of all that's holy was Dashboard component loading at all with this code then? If you wanna restrict me, then restrict me properly, not just partially. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashboard component is not declared in your AppModule, that's the problem.
Also you don't need to export the components in that case, just declare them.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution as figured out by Aakash Garg. But I fail to understand why Dashboard component was loading at all then. I'd honetly prefer if it didn't work at all, rather than work just a bit and hide intuitive solution from me.